# Can't start MySQL? Manager of pid-file quit without updating

Tags: mysql, centos

I woke up this morning to find MySQL down on my personal CentOs server, but I don't seem to be able to start it again?!?

Starting (well restarting...):

```
root@tent:~$ /sbin/service mysqld restart
 ERROR! MySQL manager or server PID file could not be found!
Starting MySQL............................................................................................................... ERROR! Manager of pid-file quit without updating
root@tent:~$ /sbin/service mysqld status
 ERROR! MySQL is running but PID file could not be found
```

Tail of error log (nothing relevant)

```
tail -f /var/lib/mysql/tent.err
110302 12:43:39 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.1.55'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server
110305 17:52:04 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/lib/mysql/tent.pid ended
```

Trying safe mode instead:

```
/usr/bin/mysqld_safe
120502 08:01:54 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin.err'.
120502 08:01:54 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
120502 08:03:38 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/lib/mysql/tent.pegproductions.com.pid ended
```

So I'm left with these running, but MySQL is still 'down' (phpMyAdmin fails, as do PHP web apps).

```
root@tent:/var/lib/mysql$ ps aux | grep -i mysql
root      1599  0.0  0.0   3712  1308 ?        S    Apr30   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --pid-file=/var/lib/mysql/tent.pid
mysql     1666  0.0  0.9 130000 19356 ?        Sl   Apr30   0:08 /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/ --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --log-error=/var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin.err --pid-file=/var/lib/mysql/tent.pid
root     11452  0.0  0.0   3224   776 pts/0    S+   08:07   0:00 grep -i mysql
```

As far as I am aware I haven't changed anything and yet it no longer starts?

Do you have any idea why or what further information I can provide?

---

```
root@tent:~$ file /var/lib/mysql/tent.pid
/var/lib/mysql/tent.pid: ASCII text
root@tent:~$ cat /var/lib/mysql/tent.pid
1672
```

Comment: Result for `file /var/lib/mysql/tent.pid`?

Comment: Added above for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
 kill -15 1666
 kill -15 1599
 rm  /var/lib/mysql/tent.pid
 rm /var/lib/mysql/tent.pegproductions.com.pid
 service mysqld start
```